# How to select more tr from HTML table

Tags: jquery, html

I have jQuery code:

```
$('td').hover(function () {
  var t = $(this),
          index = t.index(); // the position of the TD in the row, so you can find the one below it
  t.addClass('hovered'); // apply hovered class to this TD...
  t.nextAll(':lt(3)').addClass('hovered'); // ...and to the TD next to it...
  t.closest('tr')
   .nextAll(':lt(3)')
   .find('td:eq(' + index + ')')
   .addClass('hovered')
   .nextAll(':lt(3)')
   .addClass('hovered'); // ...and to the 2 below
}, function () {
  // remove the hovered class when no longer hovering
  $(this).closest('table').find('td').removeClass('hovered');
});
```

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FXy5J/1/)

How to make what select 4x4 cells? Not 2x4 +2 like demo.

Comment: You should look at the tableHover plugin, it's pretty awesome: http://p.sohei.org/stuff/jquery/tablehover/demo/demo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('td').hover(function () {
    var t = $(this),
        index = t.index(); // the position of the TD in the row, so you can find the one below it
    t.addClass('hovered'); // apply hovered class to this TD...
    t.nextAll(':lt(3)').addClass('hovered'); // ...and to the TD next to it...
    t.closest('tr').nextAll(':lt(3)').each(function(i,v){
        $('td:eq(' + index + ')', this).addClass('hovered').nextAll(':lt(3)').addClass('hovered'); // ...and to the 2 below
    })
}, function () {
    // remove the hovered class when no longer hovering
    $(this).closest('table').find('td').removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZWaqZ/)

More simplified version

```
$('td').hover(function () {
    var t = $(this),
        index = t.index(); // the position of the TD in the row, so you can find the one below it

    var trs = t.closest('tr').nextAll(':lt(3)').addBack();
    trs.find('td:eq(' + index + ')').add(trs.find('td:gt(' + (index) + '):lt(3)')).addClass('hovered');
}, function () {
    // remove the hovered class when no longer hovering
    $(this).closest('table').find('td').removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZWaqZ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td').hover(function () {
    var t = $(this),
        index = t.index(); // the position of the TD in the row, so you can find the one below it
    t.addClass('hovered'); // apply hovered class to this TD...
    t.nextAll(':lt(1)').addClass('hovered'); // ...and to the TD next to it...
    t.closest('tr').nextAll(':lt(1)').find('td:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('hovered').nextAll(':lt(1)').addClass('hovered'); // ...and to the 2 below
}, function () {
    // remove the hovered class when no longer hovering
    $(this).closest('table').find('td').removeClass('hovered');
});
```

I changed lt(3) to lt(1). See if that is what you wanted.

See the result : http://jsfiddle.net/FXy5J/3/

Comment: if I will change lt(1) will be 2x2

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectY = 4, selectX = 4

$('td').hover(function () {    
  var $cell = $(this),
    $table = $cell.parents("table"),
    x = $cell.index(),
    y = $cell.parent().index();

  $table.find("tr:eq("+y+"),tr:gt("+y+"):lt("+(selectY-1)+")")
        .find("tr:eq("+x+"),td:gt("+x+"):lt("+(selectX-1)+")")
    .addClass("hovered");
}, function(){
  $(this).parents("table")
    .find("td")
    .removeClass("hovered");    
});
```

you can choose your area with the selectX and Y vars too

http://jsfiddle.net/PKahK/2/

*updated because gt does not seem to be accepting -1 :/